# I'm creating a wazuh decoder to detect usb on client windows machine, I have received logs in archives.log but not generate alerts events

Tags: logging, decoder, wazuh

I have received logs in archives and tested them in wazuh-logtest. It runs fine but it gives nothing in alerts.log, how can I test the decoder that it working fine and generating events and alerts on wazuh dashboard?

### here is my decoder

```
   <decoder name="windows">
       <prematch>USB</prematch>
   </decoder>


  <decoder name="windows-usb">
      <parent>windows</parent>
      <prematch>EventChannel </prematch>
      <plugin_decoder offset="after_prematch">JSON_Decoder</plugin_decoder>
  </decoder>
```

---

Rules:

```
 <group name="windows-usb,syslog,">

     <rule id="500015" level="3">
        <decoded_as>windows</decoded_as>
         <description>USB log detected</description>
     </rule>
     <rule id="500016" level="3">
       <if_sid>500015</if_sid>
       <regex>USBSTOR</regex>
       <description>USB in WINDOWS Detected</description>
    </rule>
  </group>
```

---

sample Logs:

2022 Sep 13 09:59:26 (SHAHZADI-59) any->EventChannel {"win":{"system":{"providerName":"Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing","providerGuid":"{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}","eventID":"6416","version":"1","level":"0","task":"13316","opcode":"0","keywords":"0x8020000000000000","systemTime":"2022-09-13T09:59:25.2635330Z","eventRecordID":"3289631","processID":"4","threadID":"18620","channel":"Security","computer":"SHAHZADI-59","severityValue":"AUDIT_SUCCESS","message":""A new external device was recognized by the system.\r\n\r\nSubject:\r\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-18\r\n\tAccount Name:\t\tSHAHZADI-59$\r\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tWORKGROUP\r\n\tLogon ID:\t\t0x3E7\r\n\r\nDevice ID:\tUSB\VID_048D&PID_1234\2839451125099311468\r\n\r\nDevice Name:\tUSB Mass Storage Device\r\n\r\nClass ID:\t\t{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\r\n\r\nClass Name:\tUSB\r\n\r\nVendor IDs:\t\r\n\t\tUSB\VID_048D&PID_1234&REV_0200\r\n\t\tUSB\VID_048D&PID_1234\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\nCompatible IDs:\t\r\n\t\tUSB\Class_08&SubClass_06&Prot_50\r\n\t\tUSB\Class_08&SubClass_06\r\n\t\tUSB\Class_08\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\nLocation Information:\t\r\n\t\tPort_#0002.Hub_#0002\r\n\t\t""},"eventdata":{"subjectUserSid":"S-1-5-18","subjectUserName":"SHAHZADI-59$","subjectDomainName":"WORKGROUP","subjectLogonId":"0x3e7","deviceId":"USB\\VID_048D&PID_1234\\2839451125099311468","deviceDescription":"USB Mass Storage Device","classId":"{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}","className":"USB","vendorIds":"    USB\\VID_048D&PID_1234&REV_0200    USB\\VID_048D&PID_1234","compatibleIds":"    USB\\Class_08&SubClass_06&Prot_50    USB\\Class_08&SubClass_06    USB\\Class_08","locationInformation":"    Port_#0002.Hub_#0002"}}}
2022 Sep 13 09:59:26 (SHAHZADI-59) any->EventChannel {"win":{"system":{"providerName":"Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing","providerGuid":"{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}","eventID":"6416","version":"1","level":"0","task":"13316","opcode":"0","keywords":"0x8020000000000000","systemTime":"2022-09-13T09:59:25.2745239Z","eventRecordID":"3289632","processID":"4","threadID":"18620","channel":"Security","computer":"SHAHZADI-59","severityValue":"AUDIT_SUCCESS","message":""A new external device was recognized by the system.\r\n\r\nSubject:\r\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-18\r\n\tAccount Name:\t\tSHAHZADI-59$\r\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tWORKGROUP\r\n\tLogon ID:\t\t0x3E7\r\n\r\nDevice ID:\tUSBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Flash&Prod_Disk_3.0&Rev_2.00\2839451125099311468&0\r\n\r\nDevice Name:\tFlash Disk 3.0 USB Device\r\n\r\nClass ID:\t\t{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\r\n\r\nClass Name:\tDiskDrive\r\n\r\nVendor IDs:\t\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\DiskFlash___Disk_3.0________2.00\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\DiskFlash___Disk_3.0________\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\DiskFlash___\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\Flash___Disk_3.0________2\r\n\t\tFlash___Disk_3.0________2\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\GenDisk\r\n\t\tGenDisk\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\nCompatible IDs:\t\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\Disk\r\n\t\tUSBSTOR\RAW\r\n\t\tGenDisk\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\nLocation Information:\t-""},"eventdata":{"subjectUserSid":"S-1-5-18","subjectUserName":"SHAHZADI-59$","subjectDomainName":"WORKGROUP","subjectLogonId":"0x3e7","deviceId":"USBSTOR\\Disk&Ven_Flash&Prod_Disk_3.0&Rev_2.00\\2839451125099311468&0","deviceDescription":"Flash Disk 3.0 USB Device","classId":"{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}","className":"DiskDrive","vendorIds":"    USBSTOR\\DiskFlash___Disk_3.0________2.00    USBSTOR\\DiskFlash___Disk_3.0_______    USBSTOR\\DiskFlash__    USBSTOR\\Flash___Disk_3.0________2    Flash___Disk_3.0________2    USBSTOR\\GenDisk    GenDisk","compatibleIds":"    USBSTOR\\Disk    USBSTOR\\RAW    GenDisk"}}}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Wazuh.

I tried your decoder and rules with logtest and it detects properly the log and matches with the rules.
I've also tried it on a windows agent and got an alert to fire on my manager, even though when trying with logtest it does not show an alert.

Have you tried this with a live agent and plugging in an actual USB drive?
Cheers.

Comment: I have tested on the live agent and got live logs on the manager but it not generates events on wazuh dashboard.